# Enumerating pixel formats for adaptors and modes with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, enumerate

I'm trying to code an OpenGL path for my 3D engine.  The D3D path enumerates all device adaptors, all modes (by mode I mean bit depth, dimensions, available windowed, and refresh rate) for each adaptor and then all pixel formats available for the given mode and adaptor, along side certain useful caps (shader version, filter types, etc.).  So, I have broadly got the following protected functions in the class:

```
// Enumerate all back/front buffer combinations.

virtual void EnumerateBackFrontBufferCombinations(CComPtr<IDirect3D9>& d3d9);

// Enumerate all depth/stencil formats.

virtual void EnumerateDepthStencilFormats(CComPtr<IDirect3D9>& d3d9);

// Enumerate all multi-sample formats.

virtual void EnumerateMultiSampleTypes(CComPtr<IDirect3D9>& d3d9);

// Enumerate all device formats, i.e. dynamic, static, render target, etc.

virtual void EnumerateMapFormats(CComPtr<IDirect3D9>& d3d9);

// Enumerate all capabilities.

virtual void EnumerateCapabilities(CComPtr<IDirect3D9>& d3d9);
```

The adaptors are enumerated with EnumDisplayDevices, the modes (resolutions and refresh rates) are enumerated with EnumDisplaySettings, so this can be done for either GL or D3D.  The other functions I'm not so sure about with OpenGL.  What are the equivalents to the IDirect3D9's CheckDeviceType, CheckDeviceFormat, CheckDeviceMultiSampleType, CheckDepthStencilMatch?  I know I can use DescribePixelFormat, given a DC, but you kind-of need to have created the window before you can use a DC with it, but you can't create the window correctly until you know what formats you're going to use.

Any tips you can give me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but you can't create the window correctly until you know what formats you're going to use

Why?

The standard approach is:

1. Create the window.
2. Enumerate all the formats supported by the device represented by the DC of the window.
3. Call SetPixelFormat() with you favorite format to set the format.
4. Create OpenGL context.

Comment: Because the art of choosing the details of the window (fullscreen/windowed, resolution, formats) is predicated on the answers I get back concerning what's supported and what isn't.  Can these details can differ between window/full-screen?  So, I should create a window, run the tests, then destroy the window before it's shown?  Can I assume that if feature X is available from a given window (i.e. 4x multi-sample with depth buffer D24S8) it's available for all configurations on that adaptor?

Comment: AFAIK know the available formats are independent of your resolution and refresh rate. Also OpenGL is unaware of "fullscreen windows", these are just regular windows that were created in the above process and positioned to cover the whole screen. If by "features" you mean OpenGL version + extensions, then they may depend on the format you chose by SetPixelFormat.

Comment: Ok, so I can query the desktop to find available formats, and then assume those formats are valid for all combinations of enumerated display modes on the adaptor?  When it comes to testing/checking capabilities, I need to create and destroy a window for each SetPixelFormat I intend to test (there aren't actually that many combinations for front/back buffer that are interesting).  For caps, I also create the GL context and destroy that too.  The only remaining question then, is how to do this if there are multiple adaptors, or shall I just assume there's only one (the default adaptor)?

Comment: @Robinson: OpenGL isn't like Direct3D that is distincts between windowed and fullscreen mode. A fullscreen OpenGL application just maximizes it's window to cover the full screen area, turns of borders and decoration and makes it stay-on-top.

Comment: ybungalobill is right about features depending on particular formats. Specifically, avoid any format with PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT set -- it will use the software renderer.

Comment: How to enumerate ? What is the maximum integer ? Enumerate till it fails ? It's not explained anywhere.

Comment: @oOo: from [DescribePixelFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-describepixelformat): "If the function succeeds, the return value is the maximum pixel format index of the device context"